# How I can create a scala application in InteliJ and create a scala clas(Ubuntu) ?

Tags: scala, ubuntu, intellij-idea, sdk, project

Hi i want to create a first little application with scala in InteliJ. My System is Ubuntu.

I install the Scala Plugin and create a new Project (Scala -> SBT )but if I want add a scala class I dont see this option :(

[image]

[image]

I think i need the scala sdk but where and how i bind them. Why it doesnt install by the plugin :/

Comment: you should have panel called sbt in the right, try to select the root project there and refresh it.

Comment: I had something like that - try to run Build in IntelliJ and wait for couple of minutes (could take even 10 or more if your machine is slow). Just wait while all the background operations completed (progressbar in the bottom). SBT should generate `src` folder with a blue icon - there you can add the sources. At least that was the problem I experienced, I didn't wait while the background processes are finished. If no - you could add src folder by yourself and make it blue (mark it as source folder), but I do not recommend to do that manually, sbt should be aware of this folder as IntelliJ Idea.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are going to use SBT, auto-import might be a good idea. Else, you would want to manually import (see SBT tool to the right) to produce a stable, usable project.

Second, you mostly don't need to add java classes on the `project` folder, which is for the build project itself. You should be seeing a `src/main/scala` folder there instead. Try refreshing the view (right click menu, synchronize)